# vb.net calculation in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a data grid view and in the column "2" (alarmtime) I have times added as shown in the image below.

[image]

And a label in the top (label9). if the label text shows as "friday" then the "Alarm Time" cell values should add 10 minutes.
Example if the label show friday then the time should change from `16:10:00` to `16:20:00`.

My code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

Dim myform As New Form2

DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "h:mm:ss"

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("AlarmTime").Value = Me.MetroLabel2.Text And Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Frequency").Value = "Weekday" Then

        myform.Show()
        myform.msgdisply.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("UpdateName").Value

        If Me.MetroLabel9.Text = "FRIDAY" Then

            Dim iCell1 As String
            Dim dt As DateTime

            iCell1 = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("AlarmTime").Value
            dt = Format(DateTime.Parse(iCell1), "h:mm:ss")

            dt.AddMinutes(10)

            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("AlarmTime").Value = dt.ToString
        End If
next
```

Comment: The CellFormatting event would be ideal for this. Much more efficient than iterating rows   You should also turn on `Option Strict`  because `icellResult = iCell1 + "10"` is nonsense. `"10"` is not an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim dt as datetime
dt = datetime.parse(iCell1)
dt.addminutes(10)
Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("AlarmTime").Value = dt.ToString("HH:mm")
```

You can have a look at the `addminutes` method information [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: data grid view is not udpating :(

Comment: i have placed in timer tick, here is the detail code. (see above)

Comment: Are you sure that `timer` is firing? Use `Debug.Print` to evaluate `Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("AlarmTime").Value` and make sure the values are as expected.

Comment: thanks Dave i got the issue when formating the cells to "h:mm:ss". its coming with date too (ex: 1990.10.01, 6:10:00). how to format cells to time only

Comment: Ive updated the code. You should specify the string format of the time you are comparing the cell to.

Comment: Thanks Dave formating worked, however it dint add 10 minutes :(